# how to get jsonp data from url?

Tags: jquery, cross-domain

The code is very simple, I do not know why it deosnt work.

```
$.getJSON("http://localhost:8888//wm/core/controller/switches/json?jsonp=parseResponse", function(data){
alert(data);
});
```

but if i used bellow code i got jsonp data. but i don't know how to use that data. i mean to say how to store that data in a variable?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8888//wm/core/controller/switches/json?jsonp=parseResponse">
```

Comment: do you have a method called `parseResponse` in your script

Comment: try `$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:8888//wm/core/controller/switches/json",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'jsonp'
}).done(function(data){
    alert(data)
})`

Comment: i tried ur code bt its not wkring.  in firbug console i didn' see any ajax reqest

Comment: you need to check the network tab... it will not be displayed in the console as it is not a ajax request

Comment: even alert msg also not displayed when i execute that code